# Provide a unique ID for each site

Tags: feature-request, stackauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [please add a key fields to stackauth results](https://stackapps.com/questions/739/please-add-a-key-fields-to-stackauth-results)

Would it be possible to return an Id for each site in [this method](http://stackauth.com/1.0/help/method?method=sites) that won't change and so can be used in URIs? It would be more simple and reliable than relying on site URIs or order returned. Currently all of the properties returned appear to be subject to change.

Comment: I have a nagging feeling that this has been discussed and declined before, but I can't remember where...

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/739/please-add-a-key-fields-to-stackauth-results

Comment: Use the `site_url` in combination with `aliases`.