# ID number for sites

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [please add a key fields to stackauth results](https://stackapps.com/questions/739/please-add-a-key-fields-to-stackauth-results)

It would be easier if sites each had an ID, it help with keeping track of them, not only in a numerical way (which is generally easier and smaller than using name strings).

Also changes of site names (such as when a site progresses from beta, or decides it's name is not quite right during beta).

Everything else has IDs so why not sites?

Comment: It's [already been asked](http://stackapps.com/questions/739/please-add-a-key-fields-to-stackauth-results), and the status is, guess what?, declined :). +1 anyway

Comment: Please couldn't the api be made easier in this respect, I haven't used another site's api (much anyway), but this one seems quite difficult to work with in some areas, which could be made easier for the developers, which are the people who use it. I don't see any reason for not giving a  site an id, other than having to implement which take up someone's valuable time.

Comment: I find it particularly amusing that the suggested "keys" of the original post have proven to be unstable.  The only meaningful key of a site is (has been, and always will be) its address.  Even this isn't perfectly stable, which is why we return aliases as well.

Comment: A numerical Id I have asked about not initials,